# Motivation for some operators in the dyadic model of Navier Stokes equation

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, fluid-dynamics

What's the motivation for cascade operator $C_{u}, C_{d}$ (and then the dyadic version of operator $B=(u\cdot \nabla)u$), which is

$(C_{u}(u,v))_{Q} = 2^{\frac{5}{2}j}u_{\tilde{Q}}v_{\tilde{Q}}$,

$(C_{d}(u,v))_{Q} = 2^{\frac{5}{2}(j+1)}u_{Q}(\Sigma_{Q'\in C^1(Q)}v_{Q'})$he

where $j = j(Q)$,$\tilde{Q}$ is the unique parent of $Q$, $C^1(Q)$ is the set of children of $Q$

then dyadic version of $B$ is defined as

$B = C_{u}-C_{d}$

in the dyadic model of Navier Stokes equation?

Thanks for help!

Comment: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/tag/dyadic-models/

Comment: See the introduction of Kiselev-Zlatos, "On discrete models of the Euler equations," which has a nice description. See also Katz-Pavlovic, "A cheap Caffarelli-Kohn-Nirenberg inequality for Navier-Stokes equations with hyper-dissipation." Note that the model in the "cheap" Katz-Pavlovic paper is slightly different than the model in their "Finite time blow-up" paper, which I think you are looking at now.

Comment: @dalbrit, I can't find the motivation -- I mean why the dyadic version of B is the cascade difference. All the paper around these I checked  didn't talk about this, they simply write down the definition of cascade operator only.